# CommonJS imports vs ES6 imports

Tags: reactjs, import, ecmascript-6, commonjs

Here are two examples of using a non-default export. The first uses commonjs syntax, and the second uses es6. Why does the first example work, but not the second?

```
// commonjs --- works!
var ReactRouter = require('react-router')
var Link = ReactRouter.Link


// es6 --- doesn't work!
import ReactRouter from 'react-router'
var Link = ReactRouter.Link
```

I understand that I can use `import { Link } from 'react-router'` instead, but I'm just trying to wrap my head around how each import differs.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your CommonJS too, shouldn't it be `var Link = ReactRouter.Link`?

Comment: Yes, though that wasn't the issue

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`import ReactRouter` only imports the *default export*. It does not import an object of named exports which is what you're attempting to achieve in your ES6 code. If there is no default export in the module, this `ReactRouter` will be `undefined`.

As stated, `import { Link } from 'react-router'` is the dedicated syntax for importing a single *named export*.

If you want to import all *named exports* into an object, you can use the `import..as` syntax:

```
import * as ReactRouter from 'react-router';
var Link = ReactRouter.Link
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import#Description) has a super-helpful list of all the different types of imports and how they work.

Comment: So `var ReactRouter = require('react-router')` is equivalent to `import * as ReactRouter from 'react-router'`?