# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" error in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am adding react to my existing html page. by following the instructions here [enter link description here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).
And then this works just fine, until I import a different component.

my html codes:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test2</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
   <div id="like_button_container"></div>

   <!-- Load React. -->
   <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin>. 
   </script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" 
    crossorigin></script>

  <!-- Load our React component. -->
  <script src="like_button.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

my like_button.js codes:

```
    'use strict';
import Another from "./another.js"; //problem here, if you comment this line, it works.

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { liked: false };
   }

  render() {
        if (this.state.liked) {
       return 'You liked this.';
   }

  return e(
     'button',
     { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
     'Like'
     );
   }
 }

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

and my another.js codes:

```
   'use strict';

  const e = React.createElement;

 class Another extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { liked: false };
    }

  render() {
       if (this.state.liked) {
       return 'You liked this (another).';
    }

   return e(
      'button',
      { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
     'Like'
    );
   }
  }

  export default Another;
```

thank you for your answer.

edit:
i added  "type": "module" in package.json file. The latest situation is as follows;

```
  {
   "name": "test2",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "another.js",
   "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
     },
   "keywords": [],
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "type": "module"
  }
```

but it still didn't work, I get the same error in the console.

edit2:
fix the problem. Just adding ("type": "module") to package.json was not enough, I also had to add (type="module") to the script tag in the html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to tell node that you want to use `ESmodule` features** such as the `import` and `export` keywords.

To do this add this line to your `package.json` file.

```json
"type": "module"
```

An example `package.json` file that specifies type.

```json
{
    "name": "pup",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "type": "module"
}
```

You also need to add `type="module"` to the script tag where you import the file in `index.html`.

```html
<script src="like_button.js" type="module"></script>
```

**This** will stop the error that you are getting.

**Also worth looking at [commonjs vs es6 imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37050932)**

Comment: thank you your answer, i try this but I am still getting the same error. first in terminal  "npm init -y" and i create package.json file. then add ""type": "module" . doesn't work. If you want, you can copy my codes and try.

Comment: By default `"type": "module"` **isn't** added when you use `npm init -y`, did you add it manually? @malibil

Comment: yes i added manual, The latest situation is as follows;  {
  "name": "test2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "another.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module"
}

Comment: @malibil I've made a new folder with all the files set up like you said and I can't reproduce the error. Is there anything that you left off your post?

Comment: no these are all my simple files. index.html - like_button.js - another.js -package.json

Comment: @malibil My bad sorry, I spent 5 minutes staring at your javascript and completely forgot about html.  I think I've fixed the problem now, and made an edit to the post.

Comment: thank you so much, now fix the my problem.